# How to add a floating text on a scrollable canvas in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I want to create a floating text (does not scroll even if the canvas below scrolls) in tkinter. I tried searching for floating labels but could not find. 
Right now the parent of the canvas is a frame which is scrollable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added another canvas on top of that canvas with the same parent frame and lifted it up by

```
tk.Misc.lift(floating_canvas)
```

Now the below canvas is scrolabble while the above one is static